# Understanding the decreasing influence of text embedding in Text-to-Image diffusion models: A Mathematical perspective

Tags: papers, math, diffusion-models

I've been reading the paper titled **[eDiff-I: Text-to-Image Diffusion Models with an Ensemble of Expert Denoisers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.01324.pdf)** by *Yogesh Balaji et. al*. Consider the following excerpt from the abstract of the paper

> Large-scale diffusion-based generative models have led to
> breakthroughs in text-conditioned high-resolution image synthesis,
> demonstrating complex text comprehension and outstanding zero-shot
> generalization. Starting from random noise, such text-to-image
> diffusion models gradually synthesize images in an iterative fashion
> while conditioning on text prompts. We find that their synthesis
> behavior qualitatively changes throughout this process: **Early in
> sampling, generation strongly relies on the text prompt to generate
> text-aligned content, while later, the text conditioning is almost
> entirely ignored, and the task changes to producing outputs of high
> visual fidelity.**

Afaik, the text embedding always play a role in the denoising process. So, how does the role or influence of the embedding decrease over time while sampling an image from diffusion model? Can someone provide mathematical explanation for understanding the decrease of the influence of text embedding?

Comment: _"theory will only take you so far"_

Comment: I think that it's only backed by intuition... if you strongly guide the model using text, the text will highly impact the generation, limiting the "creativity" of the model... in addition to this, small change to the text, which might me insignificant for humans, will strongly impact the generation... instead "conditioning" your generation only at the beginning, will leave the model enough freedom to steer towards that conditioning to generate good images